# dynamically changing dates in a temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So i have a very specific task. I run some sql statements within which there is a temp table which contains date ranges specific to countries.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO #dateRange(durationDesc, contryCode,startDate,endDate)
VALUES ('Weekly - TY','UK','20160919','20160925')
      ,('Weekly - LY','UK','20150921','20150927')
      ,('Weekly - LW','UK','20150912','20150918')
```

So, corresponding week previous year. The other range is month to date.

Whats the best way to do this? I'd prefer one where i only need to enter one date and the rest can be updated.

Any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Could you clarify what it is you are trying to do? Also what RDBMS are we talking about? SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server. So currently i am having to change the dates manually everytime i need to run the statements. I use the date ranges to connect to the tables and return the data grouped by those date ranges. I need a more dynamic way to change these dates instead of me having to change dates every week.

Comment: Can you please review this: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). Specifically pay attention to `Expected Output`. If you follow the guidelines from that link, it will be a lot easier for us to understand what you want done, and easier for the people around here to help you.

Comment: you might be able to swap the date strings for variables that get populated by logic - please see comment from TT regarding expected output - we need to know the logic behind the 6 dates you are showing (you may only be mentioning 4 dates)  - none of your example date ranges looks like 'month to date' - if you take today's date and subtract (DAY(getdate()) - 1) days from it, you get the first day of the month - so can that help you generate a 'month-to-date' range?

Comment: Sorry guys for not explaining the question properly. Yes month to date isnt there but its one of the date ranges, i only wanted to give an idea of whats going on. My expected output is to replave the strings with something logical that uses a command e.g. dateadd so it had minimal human interaction of changing dates manually each week. It seems tweray's answer makes sense for now, so will try that to derive my dates

Answer (score 0):

You can always get current system datetime by [GETDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx), and then modify it accordingly by [DATEADD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

For example:

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) -- Result in 1 year prior the current system datetime.
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 13, GETDATE()) -- Result in 13 months after the current system datetime.
```

In your code snippet you seems to be converting the datetime into `yyyymmdd` string format (Although I highly doubt the necessity), which can be achieve by a `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()), 112)
```

For example if today is 10/26/2016, then it should show result as 1 year prior to today in yyyymmdd format, `20151026`

Comment: That makes sense tweray. So where i have the string i can use a variable which would have the assigned value of using the dateadd functions?

Comment: @Faiz yes, although I don't suggest to store date as string